# A new data conversion issue in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data column with two kind of date-format values, the numeric one (es. "38169") and the string one (es. "01/03/2004", always in format "%d/%m/%Y"). I cannot transform them in the same date-format and reconvert them in the standard date-format "%Y-%m-%d".

Forom the example below, I would like to transform the variable date_first in the variable date_clean

Additional information:

The database is imported from Excel.
The etherogeneous date format is the result of a string alteration happening in both excel and R

```
data <- data.frame(date_all=c(NA,"38169","37926","01/03/2004 --- 01/03/2004"),
                  date_first=c(NA,"38169","37926","01/03/2004"))
                  
desidered_data <- data.frame(date_all=c(NA,"38169","37926","01/03/2004 --- 01/03/2004"),
                  date_first=c(NA,"38169","37926","01/03/2004"),
                  date_clean=c(NA,2004-07-01,2003-11-01,2004-03-01))

> desidered_data
                   date_all date_first date_clean
1                      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2                     38169      38169 2004-07-01
3                     37926      37926 2003-11-01
4 01/03/2004 --- 01/03/2004 01/03/2004 2004-03-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option -

```
change_mix_date <- function(x) {
  #empty date vector to store the results
  new_date <- as.Date(NA)
  #Check for values that have only numbers in them (excel dates)
  inds <- grepl('^\\d+$', x)
  #Change excel date to date class
  new_date[inds] <- as.Date(as.numeric(x[inds]), origin = '1899-12-30')
  #Change remaining ones to date class using as.Date
  new_date[!inds] <- as.Date(x[!inds], '%d/%m/%Y')
  #Return output. 
  new_date
}

data$date_clean <- change_mix_date(data$date_first)

#                   date_all date_first date_clean
#1                      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#2                     38169      38169 2004-07-01
#3                     37926      37926 2003-11-01
#4 01/03/2004 --- 01/03/2004 01/03/2004 2004-03-01
```

Comment: how does one decides upon the origin = '1899-12-30'?

Comment: That is standard origin for excel dates. For R, the origin is '1970-01-01'

Comment: 1899-12-30 is a very common origin. In most cases the origin is either 1899-12-30, 1900-1-1, or 1970-1-1. You can test around a bit to find out which of these match your expected output. If you don't know the expected output it is worth looking into what basetime your application uses

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case_when` for this:

```
data %>%
  mutate(date_clean = case_when(grepl("\\d{5}", date_first) ~ as.Date(as.numeric(date_first), origin = "1899-12-30"),
                                TRUE ~ as.Date(date_first, format = "%d/%m/%Y")))
```

Comment: If you're onnly checking between 2 possibilities, there isn't really an advantage in using `case_when` over the base `ifelse`, plus the syntax is harder to read

Comment: You are not wrong. I personally find the syntax very readable and it allows for expansion if new cases appear but your reasoning is sound

Comment: Yeah I guess I shouldn't say the syntax is hard to read necessarily, but it is really different from most other R syntax and would definitely be confusing for someone who isn't familiar with that specific function